# How to create a new column with the value of the first column divided by 2

Tags: mariadb

I'm new to mariadb. I need a code to add a new column with the values in the first column divided by 2.
I have a table (named numbers) in mariadb with only one columun (named value_1, with 4 rows, values: 10, 12, 14 and 16). I need to create a new column, named value_2, with the values: 5, 6, 7 and 8 (that is, value_1 divided by 2).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE numbers ADD COLUMN value_2 INT AS (value_1 / 2) VIRTUAL;
```